# Define specific express project

Tags: node.js, express

I'd love to be able to define a specific express framework of files so I have a boilerplate of the things I use, the way I use them every time I start a new project. Is there a way to do this within express or am I just going be copying and pasting folders?

Comment: What do you want to automate beyond copying the framework to a new project directory?

Comment: Yeoman may be of interest - you can create your own scaffold

Comment: @Yashua yeah, I think I was thinking of Yeoman! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Express 4 an the express `app` variable can be used within the context of a route / as a router.

You can `export` the `app` variable and pass it along and make your express apps more modular this way.

**my-reusable-app.js**

```
const app = express()

app.get('/hello', sayHello)

export default app
```

**app.js**

```
import myApp from './my-reusable-app'

const app = express()

app.use(myApp)

export default app
```